# App Script not triggering importrange in second spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 spreadsheets.  The first contains data which is updated by an HTMLservice web app.  The second uses importrange to include the data from the first.  The second sheet does not show changed data from the first if the web app updates the file.  The changed information is in the first sheet, but not showing in the second. Note that these are in two difference spreadsheet files.  If I manually change a field in the first sheet the second will show the changed data from both the manual edit and the data posted via the web app.  Is there something I need to do to tell the first sheet to communicate out any changes made by an apps script post?

Karl

Comment: ImportRange often exhibits an irregular delay; how long have you left it? You might try adding a volatile function to your client sheet such as 
   =Now()
but the only reliable way to make the data show up immediately is to drop it in there with code.

Comment: @Tim (Thought I commented on this a while ago...)    I edited the main spreadsheet data with my script 2.5 hours ago and the data has yet to change in the second spreadsheet. I just Opened that second spreadsheet as opposed to having it sitting open on my system.  My experience with ImportRange has been that changes are displayed within a minute, most often seconds of manual edits or changes from a Form entry.  So I am thinking I need to have something in my code to communicate the change back to some server?

Comment: Agree that 2.5 hours should be plenty, so that just leaves the volatile function to look into? :)

Comment: @Tim  I put =NOW() in the main sheet and it is not helping.  At least not after a 15 minute wait.  I can let that site longer but it is not acceptable in my book.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it looks like you'll have to code & execute the data transfer as part of the source routine

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

I ended up dropping the ImportRange and added a function to my Web App script to update the second file. The function simply copies the contents to the second file. Since the second sheet is only reporting a statistic this is a semi-acceptable compromise.  I did this as a function in order to allow me to set a Trigger on just that function on Manual EDits of the main spreadsheet for completeness.

Karl